# How to set onEachSide at controller level on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to set `onEachSide` at controller level on `laravel`?

on `blade` we use:

```
{{ $records->onEachSide(2)->links() }}
```

How this can be done at controller level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Record::paginate(10)->onEachSide(2);
```

Comment: I never thought that wouldbe possilbe.

Comment: better to add into controller section, so that View page loads fastly!